# Anaconda with Tensorflow: No module named any_pb2

Tags: python, anaconda, tensorflow

I have just installed Anaconda in a Ubuntu 14.04. Then I installed tensorflow using

```
conda install -c https://conda.anaconda.org/jjhelmus tensorflow
```

Then I installed protobuf

```
conda install -c https://conda.anaconda.org/anaconda protobuf
```

However, I am not able to solve this issue:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/daniel/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/spyderlib/widgets/externalshell/sitecustomize.py", line 699, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)
  File "/home/daniel/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/spyderlib/widgets/externalshell/sitecustomize.py", line 81, in execfile
    builtins.execfile(filename, *where)
  File "/home/daniel/Documents/Cursos/UnB/Metodos Computacionais/2016/Notas de Aula/Part II - Aula 1 Regression Linear Models/biasVersusVarianceSeveralData.py", line 8, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "/home/daniel/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "/home/daniel/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 69, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.training import training as train
  File "/home/daniel/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/training.py", line 149, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.training.saver import generate_checkpoint_state_proto
  File "/home/daniel/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 29, in <module>
    from google.protobuf.any_pb2 import Any
ImportError: No module named any_pb2
```

Comment: Have you considered taking a different path to installation and using the [instructions on the TensorFlow site](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/get_started/os_setup.html#pip-installation)? Since TensorFlow source code is constantly being updated it is hard to guarantee a build that will install, but checking the Continuous Integration site should be of value.

Comment: Great! I did it using the installation direct from google! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Use the [instructions on the TensorFlow site](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/get_started/os_setup.html#pip-installation).

TLDR;

I am posting this as an answer because people don't look for answers in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my comment on the issue from github, hope this helps.

"For anyone else who is running into the same issue, I was also having similar problems when trying to import tensorflow on notebook via jupyter. The modules were installed using conda. After spending two days on it without any success (kept getting the same, no module any_pb2/contrib), it was obvious it was a notebook problem and not tensorflow related since I could import tensorflow from python shell. So I decided to switch back to vanilla python and installed everything manually (tensorflow via pip & got rid of jupyter & installed ipython instead) and now I am able to import tensorflow from my ipython notebook."

Original comment link: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/1161#issuecomment-188664103

Answer (score -1):

The following worked for me:

conda install -c https://conda.anaconda.org/jjhelmus tensorflow